# ListView Binding INotifyPropertyChanged not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, binding, prism

I have a `ListView` which I bind to an `ObservableCollection` with the generic type `MyCommand`. When I change a property in an `MyCommand` object the `ListView` is not updated.

**Converter:**

```
public class CommandToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Commands}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource CommandToStringConverter}}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**View CodeBehind:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainViewModel();
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
using Prism.Mvvm;

public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyCommand> _commands;
    public ObservableCollection<MyCommand> Commands
    {
        get { return _commands; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _commands, value); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //setup test data
        Commands = new ObservableCollection<MyCommand>(new [] {
            new MyCommand(
                CommandType.HotKey, 
                new [] {
                    new MyCommandBinding(HotKey.F5),
                    new MyCommandBinding(HotKey.F1)
                })
            });
    }        
}
```

**Models:**

```
public enum CommandType
{
    HotKey
}

public enum HotKey
{
    F1,
    F5,
    A,
    B,
    C
}

public class MyCommand : BindableBase
{
    private CommandType _commandType;
    public CommandType CommandType
    {
        get { return _commandType; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _commandType, value); }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MyCommandBinding> _commandBindings;
    public ObservableCollection<MyCommandBinding> CommandBindings 
    {
        get { return _commandBindings; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _commandBindings, value); }
    }

    public MyCommand(CommandType commandType, IEnumerable<MyCommandBinding> bindings)
    {
        CommandType = commandType;
        CommandBindings = new ObservableCollection<MyCommandBinding>(bindings);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var text = string.Empty;
        foreach(var binding in CommandBindings)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)) text += " + ";
            text += binding.HotKey.ToString();
        }
        return CommandType.ToString() + ", " + text;
    }  
}

public class MyCommandBinding : BindableBase
{
    private HotKey _hotKey;
    public HotKey HotKey
    {
        get { return _hotKey; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _hotKey, value); }
    }

    public MyCommandBinding(HotKey hotKey)
    {
        HotKey = hotKey;
    }
}
```

Now when I change the property `Commands[0].CommandBindings[0].HotKey = HotKey.A;` the view doesn gets updated.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I'm using now an `ItemTemplate` and an converter and I still have the same behavior (initial post is updated). I makes no difference if I call the `ToString` method in my converter or if I make use of a property. And like Brian Lagunas pointed out it updates the view if I reassign the `Commands` list.

Comment: Does `CommandBindings = bindings;` in the MyCommand constructor actually compile? Besides that you should also show us the ItemTemplate of the ListView.

Comment: What ItemTemplate are you using in your ListView?

Comment: ups just wrote it here.. I'll correct it

Comment: I use the default item template. no changes

Comment: The ToString method of `MyCommand` gets called and displayed (this works. just not on updates)

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are using the ToString of the objects to represent the display of the objects in the ListView.  ToString is not re-queried on property changes.

Comment: ah thanks! forcing it by using the stringformat property seems not to work

Comment: No.  The only way I know is to reset the ListView ItemSource, but that probably isn't omething you want to do.  Just use a proper item template in your Listview

Comment: @Dr.Fre You'll need to bind to the `CommandBindings` property with a binding converter that does something like `string.Join(" + ", (IEnumerable<string>)value)`. However, that binding will also not be triggered if you replace a collection element in CommandBindings. You would have to always replace the whole collection.

Comment: @Dr.Fre You'll need both, The converter is used in a Binding in the ItemTemplate.